# pint-pandas import error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pint.quantity' (pint is imported)

Tags: python, pint

I am trying to use pint-pandas, but it errors on import with a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pint.quantity'`.
MRE from the pint-pandas github 'basic example' (because it errors on `import pint_pandas`, i call the version numbers direct)
FWIW: pandas itself work fine. I work in Anaconda jupyter notebook, with packages installed using `conda install`.
Versions: python = 3.9.13 , pandas = 1.4.4 (now 1.5.1) , pint   = 0.20.1 , pint-pandas = 0.2

```
from platform import python_version
import pandas as pd
import pint
import pint_pandas
```

[image]

Comment: Digging through the pint-pandas `setup.cfg`, I see the requirement is `python_requires = >=3.8   
  
 install_requires =   
    pint>=0.20.1   
    pandas>=1.5`
Even though the Anaconda stable version for pandas is 1.4.4, I forced it to 1.5.1 via conda-forge. Problem with pint-pandas persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After flagging this issue to pint-pandas team on github, the issue was raised and package now updated to 0.3. Thanks!